# bootstrap 4 template text formatting issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am unable to fix text formatting of a 2 line text

currently, it looks like this

[image]

I want to show it like this

[image]

Here is my HTML code I am using bootstrap

```
<label for="checkbox-group-1588093203851" class="radio-group-label">
<span class="mr-2">2.1.2</span> For the purposes of serving its clients, does the Reporting Firm maintain ongoing relationships with regulated financial institutions or other regulated professional service providers (e.g. referrals)?
<span class="formbuilder-required">*</span>
<span class="tooltip-element" tooltip="This does not include business operating accounts at financial institutions or professional services acquired for the functioning of the entity itself (e.g. legal advice to the entity, accountancy services for the entity, etc.).">?</span></label>
```

Comment: Could you explain clearly please the differences between the two photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, then you can simply add class `d-inline-flex` to the `label` and wrap the question text in another `span`, so that there are only two direct children of `label` flex container.

Check the updated HTML below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="checkbox-group-1588093203851" class="radio-group-label d-inline-flex">
  <span class="mr-2">2.1.2</span>
  <span>
    For the purposes of serving its clients, does the Reporting Firm maintain ongoing relationships with regulated financial institutions or other regulated professional service providers (e.g. referrals)?
    <span class="formbuilder-required">*</span>
    <span class="tooltip-element" tooltip="This does not include business operating accounts at financial institutions or professional services acquired for the functioning of the entity itself (e.g. legal advice to the entity, accountancy services for the entity, etc.).">?</span>
  </span>
</label>
```